# Probability of a sequence being increasing after being chosen without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> A container contains 40 numbered pieces of paper 1 through 40. Someone reaches their hand in and sequentially chooses all of them **without replacement**. What is the probability that the 5th, the 10th, and the 30th are all increasing?

Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_{40}$ be the results of choosing each of the pieces of paper. We want to compute

$$P(Y_5<Y_{10}<Y_{30})$$

My thinking is that due to the fact that without replacement choices are exchangable, we may equivalently compute $P(Y_1<Y_{2}<Y_{3})$. Thus, there are $\binom{40}{3}$ distinct increasing choices, and there are 37 left after making these. Finally, there are $40!$ elements in the sample space. Therfore,

$$P(Y_5<Y_{10}<Y_{30})=\frac{\binom{40}{3}37!}{40!}$$.

This problem was from the exchangeability section in my prob textbook. Was exchangeability really required in this question? Am I missing something that would make it easier if I had used exchangeability?

Comment: Why do you think your answer is incorrect?

Comment: @user6247850 Ah I was looking at the wrong solution in the book I indeed got it right. Thank you! I edited the question with a follow up.

Comment: @angryavian Wouldn't my proof still be correct without "exchangability"?

Comment: @angryavian Even if I didn't know that sampling without replacement is exchangable, I could have just said there are $\binom{40}{3}$ increasing ways to choose the corresponding positions, then the others would all be filled in via $37!$ ways of choosing them. Could you help me understand how my proof relied on exchangability?

Comment: @user2950916 This is a "toy" problem, in the sense that with or without exchangeability, it's fairly easy. You used exchangeability when you argued that $\mathbb P(Y_5<Y_{10} < Y_{30}) = \mathbb P(Y_1<Y_2<Y_3)$, because you exchanged the random variables without changing the probability. In toy problems, "all routes are the same", in the sense that following some trivial changes, any two different looking proofs can be made to look very similar to each other. Your approach that "doesn't" use exchangeability hides it very cleverly, so that even you don't notice it (although you are correct)

Comment: @user2950916 can you share the name of the textbook , please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know the triplet $(Y_5, Y_{10}, Y_{30})$ is exchangeable, then it has the same distribution as $(Y_{10}, Y_5, Y_{30})$ or $(Y_{30}, Y_5, Y_{10})$, and so on. Therefore,

$$P(Y_5 < Y_{10} < Y_{30}) = P(Y_5 < Y_{30} < Y_{10}) = P(Y_{10} < Y_5 < Y_{30}) = P(Y_{10} < Y_{30} < Y_5) = P(Y_{30} < Y_5 < Y_{10}) = P(Y_{30} < Y_{10} < Y_5).$$
Moreover, these six probabilities sum to $1$, so each must equal $1/6$ which is the same as your answer.